# Винительный или родительный?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

*Напиться три литра пива* или *напиться трех литров пива*? *Наесться одну буханку хлеба* или *наесться одной буханки хлеба?*

Answer (score 1):

[НАПИ́ТЬСЯ](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ozhegov-term-17059.htm), *сов.*
**1.** *чего.* Выпить чего-нибудь в большом количестве. *Напиться холодной воды.*
(В МАС:  ***чего*** и ***без доп.***)
**2.** *чем.* Попить вдоволь, утолив жажду. *Напиться квасом.*

**Напиться** (чего? Р. п.) **пива** (без указания количества).
**Напиться** (чем? Т. п.) **тремя литрами пива.**
*...можно выпить бутылку залпом и не утолить жажду, а можно небольшими глотками **напиться одним стаканом.***

[НАЕ́СТЬСЯ](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ozhegov-term-16673.htm), *сов.*
**1.** *чего.* Поесть чего-нибудь вдоволь, в большом количестве. *Наесться мороженого.*
**2.** *чем.* Поесть чего-нибудь досыта. *Наесться хлебом.*

**Наесться** (чего? Р. п.) **хлеба** (без указания количества).
**Наесться** (чем? Т. п.) **одной буханкой хлеба.**
Из Библии: *A сколько корзин остатков вы собрали, когда четыре тысячи человек **наелись семью хлебами?***

Answer (score 0):

*Напиться тремя литрами пива*

*Наесться одной буханкой хлеба*

Это творительный падеж. Падежный вопрос: "кем? чем?"